# need help on android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am newbie in android programming.  I like to create a widget to update network status such as signal level, operator details.  Can i update these data on an interval of a second.   It is possible in widget.  If yes kindly provide a solution to do it.
thanks

Comment: this will help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this natively because `android:updatePeriodMillis` is restricted to a minimum period of 30 minutes.

You can bypass this limit by adding a service that will update your widget to the AlarmManager(which does support intervals less than 30 minutes):

```
final Intent _intent = new Intent(context, MyUpdateService.class);
final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, _intent, 0);
final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 60000;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending)
```